# How to override !important style from external package in angular

Tags: css, angular

Problem is I can't override CSS property in my project because of external CSS file has `!important` on my target property and my `style.css` is loaded after that external CSS file

**example:**

package css style:

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    color: red !important;
    ...
}
```

my style.css style:

```
.ui-slider {
    color: red !important;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your style like this:

```
body .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    color: red !important;
}
```

If your style is loaded after the external style, than the external style will be overridden by your style.

By adding the `body` selector to the rule, your rule will be more precise than the one in the external file, and it will have higher priority even if your style will be loaded before the external style.

Answer (score 1):

If your css is loaded after external css, then your css will overwrite it.

ie.

**external.css**

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    color: red !important;
    ...
}
```

**internal.css**

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    color: blue !important;
    ...
}
```

**outcome:**
color: blue;

Answer (score 1):

Try to you add one your own class (ex:sb-slider) in above this control,
then use like below

```
.sb-slider {
  .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
     color: blue !important;
     ...
  }
}
```

I hope this is help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.ui-slider[style] {
    color: red !important;
    ...
}
```